# A generic error occurred in GDI+.' Is there something wrong with the code snippet by Microsoft when it comes to saving a compressed img

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, bitmap

I am working on compressing images and but I keep getting:

*System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'*

On these lines:

```
                cloneImage.Save(saveImagePath, typeOfImageEncoder, cirarEncoderParameters);
                image.Save(saveImagePath, typeOfImageEncoder, cirarEncoderParameters);
```

I've tried to clone the BitMap image in my code but the result are still the same. I've done some reading that it might be user rights but i've checked the path folder and i have all types I need for reading and executing.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace CompressImages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var small = @"C:\Temp\Dev area\imageCompress\Original Images\potato-small.jpg";
            var medium = @"C:\Temp\Dev area\imageCompress\Original Images\potato-medium.jpg";
            var large = @"C:\Temp\Dev area\imageCompress\Original Images\potato-large.jpg";
            var savePath = @"C:\Temp\Dev area\imageCompress\Compressed images";

            CompressImage(small, savePath);

        }

        public static void CompressImage(string imagePath, string saveImagePath)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo typeOfImageEncoder;
            using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imagePath))
            {
                if (imagePath.Contains(".jpg"))
                {
                    typeOfImageEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                else if (imagePath.Contains(".png"))
                {
                    typeOfImageEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException();
                }

                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder cirarEncoder =
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

                EncoderParameters cirarEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

                EncoderParameter cirarEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(cirarEncoder, 50L);
                cirarEncoderParameters.Param[0] = cirarEncoderParameter;

                //Bitmap cloneImage = (Bitmap) image.Clone();
                //cloneImage.Save(saveImagePath, typeOfImageEncoder, cirarEncoderParameters);
                image.Save(saveImagePath, typeOfImageEncoder, cirarEncoderParameters);
            }
        }     

        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            // GDI+ is the portion of the Windows operating system that provides two-dimensional vector graphics, imaging, and typography
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

            foreach (var codec in codecs)
            {
                // Global Unique IDentifier === Guid
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code can be found here.

[How to: Set JPEG Compression Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Note that `savePath` looks like a folder, not a filename? Do you already have a folder there called `Compressed images`?

Comment: @canton7 Yes i've created the folder Compressed images were I want to store my compressed images

Comment: Yes, but when you save a Bitmap, you save it to a file, not a folder. You need to add a destination file name.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @jimi and @Canton7 I've notice that I need to change my saving path to a file instead of using a variable that contains a directorypath.

```
            image.Save(saveImagePath + "\FileName.jpg", typeOfImageEncoder, cirarEncoderParameters);
```

Comment: Note, use `Path.Combine` (or `Path.Join` if you're using .NET Core), instead of string concatenation to join paths